# Bitcoin wallet backup "0/unconfirmed"

Tags: bitcoin

I get an "11dbexception" error saying "not enough space" and some transactions won't show up on the list. I've checked on Google, then erased everything but the current `wallet.dat` file from my Bitcoin folder. I tried the same with an old backup (few months old).

In both cases I let the BTC client run for several hours, receiving blocks but my balance stayed at 0, with 0 confirmation on every transactions on my list.

I just tried to do the same with the `-rescan` option but still at 0.

With more than 300 wallet transactions, will this backup process take forever to confirm? Or, should I try some different recovery/fix method?

I'm on Windows XP with Bitcoin 0.3.22.

Comment: There is actually a Bitcoin Stack Exchange beta site, where you may have more luck with this question - http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the latest release! Again only put in your wallet.dat, let it download the blockchain. This can really take some time (up to several hours) until your blockchain has caught up with the current status - then everything should be fine.

If there are still transactions missing run a -rescan after the blockchain was downloaded completely

Comment: yeah the last version did the trick, and it did take forever to synchronise with the network ...pff I can sleepnow ! thx ;)